# Retrieve data from a MS Access table

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I am trying to create a Banking windows form as an assignment.

I am able to log users in with the below code. It reads from an MS Access database:

```
myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
myConnection.Open()

Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Customer_Id = (SELECT [ID] FROM Customer WHERE Cust_Name = '" & txtName.Text & "') AND PIN =" & Convert.ToInt32(txtPin.Text) & ";", myConnection)
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

Dim userFound As Boolean = False

While dr.Read
    userFound = True
    loggedInName = txtName.Text
End While
```

Now, I am trying to retrieve the *Balance* value from the *Account* table for the user which has just logged in.

Is there a way to use the above code to do that? If not, then what is the best way?

Comment: I hope my bank uses parameters with their SQL queries.

Comment: Look into SQL parameters. This is open to SQL injection. they aren't hard to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Item Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkt33ftf(v=vs.110).aspx) of the DataReader to get your value:

```
While dr.Read
    userFound = True
    loggedInName = txtName.Text 

    Dim dblBalance As Double = 0.0

    'This shouldn't be a nullable field, but just in case:
    If dr.Item("Balance") <> DBNull.Value Then

        dblBalance = Convert.ToDouble(dr.Item("Balance"))

    End If
End While
```